# Expected time to absorption for Markov chains

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

Let $X$ be a Markov chain with countable state space $S$ and transition kernel $P$, and let $ T = [ z \in S : \ P(z,z) = 1 ]$. Let $\tau = \inf [ k \geq 0 : X_k \in T ]$ and assume that $ \mathbb{E}^x [ \tau ] < \infty $ for all initial conditions $x \in S$. I would like to show that function $f(x) = \mathbb{E}^x [ \tau ] $ satisfies

$$ Pf(x) - f(x) = -1, \ x \in S \setminus T \text{ and } f(x) = 0, \ x \in T. $$

For $x \in T$ we would immediately get $\tau = 0$. Hence,

$$ f(x) =  \mathbb{E}^x [ \tau ] = 0, \ x \in T. $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\in S\setminus T$ we have $\tau\ge1$ and hence
\begin{align}
f(x)&=E^x\tau \\ 
&=E^x\inf\{k\ge0\colon X_k\in T\} \\ 
&=E^x\inf\{k\ge1\colon X_k\in T\} \\ 
&=E^xE^{X_1}\inf\{k\ge1\colon X_k\in T\} \\ 
&=E^xE^{X_1}(1+\inf\{j\ge0\colon X_{j+1}\in T\}) \\ 
&=1+E^xE^{X_1}\inf\{j\ge0\colon X_{j+1}\in T\} \\ 
&=1+\sum_{y\in S}P(x,y)E^y\inf\{j\ge0\colon X_j\in T\} \\ 
&=1+\sum_{y\in S}P(x,y)E^y\tau \\ 
&=1+\sum_{y\in S}P(x,y)f(y) \\ 
&=1+Pf(x), 
\end{align}
so that $Pf(x)-f(x)=-1$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: I think that the index in the sum should be $y$.

Comment: @user514580 : Right. Fixed that.

Comment: Do we really need to condition on $X_1$?

Comment: @user514580 : Yes, this is the essential part of the derivation. I cannot see how to do it without this conditioning, in some form.